# How to extract ListView Item using Xamarin Prism EventToCommand behaviour

Tags: listview, xamarin, prism

I am using Prism Library with Xamarin Forms and trying to use the EventToCommandBehavior described [here](http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Xamarin-Forms/6-EventToCommandBehavior/) to attach the ItemTapped behaviour on a Listview.

When the ItemTappedCommand delegate is executed the event arguments are null which means I cannot extract the ListView Item.

Below is my ViewModel code:

```
 private DelegateCommand<ItemTappedEventArgs> _itemTappedCommand;
    public RecipeListViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {

        RefreshDataCommand = new Command(async () => await RefreshData());
        _itemTappedCommand = new DelegateCommand<ItemTappedEventArgs>(args => {
            var b = args; // args is null
            _navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(Recipe));
        });
    }

public DelegateCommand<ItemTappedEventArgs> ItemTappedCommand { get { return _itemTappedCommand; } }
```

This is my XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Recipes}"
            HasUnevenRows="false"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshDataCommand}"
            x:Name="lvRecipes">
        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" />
        </ListView.Behaviors>
        <ListView.Header>..........
.....</ListView>
```

Answer (score 5):

As Brian indicated you're going about it the wrong way. For example say I have a Collection of strings just to make it simple but it could be a collection of anything.

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableRangeCollection<string>()
        {
            "Fred Smith",
            "John Thompson",
            "John Doe"
        };

        ItemTappedCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(OnItemTappedCommandExecuted);
    }

    public ObservableRangeCollection<string> People { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand<string> ItemTappedCommand { get; }

    private void OnItemTappedCommandExecuted(string name) =>
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name);
}
```

My ListView would then simply need to do the following:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ListView.Behaviors>
        <b:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" 
                                  EventName="ItemTapped"
                                  EventArgsParameterPath="Item" />
    </ListView.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

The command in your ViewModel should be expecting the exact type of Object in the Collection that you're binding to the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`. To properly use it you simply need to specify the path in the `EventArgs` which in this case would just be `Item`.

Comment: what is "b" assigned to?

Comment: It comes the the Prism.Behaviors namespace in the Prism.Forms assembly

Comment: What is exactly is `item` here from where it comes.

Comment: @Arvindraja if you're referring to the Item in EventArgsParameterPath, the parameter name should tell you where that comes from. It is a property of the EventArgs returned by the ItemTapped event.

Answer (score 3):

Control EventArgs aren't passed to the ViewModel. That breaks the MVVM pattern.  Just use either an EventArgsParameterPath or an EventArgsConverter to pass exactly what you need to your ViewModel.